# How to make text appear at the top left corner?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, user-experience

Here is the UI prototype I am trying to implement

[image]

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54cwezo6/) of what I currently have  and the CSS I have tried

```
.help_header {
     transform: translateY(-100px); 
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
 }
```

Does anyone know how to make the text appear at the top, not the bottom?

I tried [padding-bottom](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding-bottom.asp) which made the most sense to me(distance between the bottom border of div and the text) but that didn't work. I also tried [margin-bottom](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin-bottom.asp) and [transform:translateY](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)
 but those properties didn't work either.

Comment: vertical-align: top; should do the trick

Comment: @MathijsRutgers Thanks, that should be the answer!

Comment: You said it's working because, there is somewhere else set the span to `display:inline-block` I think, otherwise it won't do it [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/54cwezo6/1/).

Comment: @Pangloss Never used display:inline-block.

Comment: Or set it to float or anything make it not as an inline element, anyway you have got it working, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html:

```
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <img  src="http://imgur.com/x45xmG3.jpg" />
   <div class="help_header">
    <span>Contact us</span>
    <span>Forum</span>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
body {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
#header {
height: 100px;
float:left;
}

.help_header {
float:right;
}
```

are you looking for somting like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KingPyrox/54cwezo6/4/)